# PIG : Split array elements into different rows

Tags: arrays, apache-pig, flatten

Say the schema is like:

```
gen_data: {a: chararray,f: chararray}
```

**input:** `(4,[IAB9, IAB9-7, IAB1, IAB9-30])`

**desired output:**

```
(4,IAB9)

(4,IAB9-7)

(4,IAB1)

(4,IAB9-30)
```

I want to get each array element in a different row along with other columns.

I am unable to get the above desired output. Please help me achieve this output. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use '[' as delimiter and load the data.This will give you
4, and IAB9, IAB9-7, IAB1, IAB9-30].Remove the , in the first column and ']' in the second column.Then use STRSPLIT or TOKENIZE and TOBAG

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage('[') AS (f1:chararray,f2:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(f1,',',''),REPLACE(f2,']','');
C = FOREACH B GENERATE $0,FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($1,','));
D = FOREACH C GENERATE $0,FLATTEN(TOBAG($1,$2,$3,$4)); -- Try TOBAG(*) if this doesn't work
DUMP D;
```